# MSO Conditionals and ERB Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ms-office, erb

I'm trying to embedded ruby content in a MSO conditional in a mailer.html.erb in a rails server.

Because dosen't seem to work since href renders "www.example.com/edit/<%= @user[:id] %>/<%= @user[:reset_digest] %>" for mso.

```
<!--[if mso]>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;" align="center">
                  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.example.com/doctores/edit/<%= @user[:id] %>/<%= @user[:reset_digest] %>" style="height:42px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:170px;" arcsize="15%" strokecolor="#3AAEE0" fillcolor="#3AAEE0">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;">
<![endif]-->
            <a href="https://www.example.com/doctores/edit/<%= @user[:id] %>/<%= @user[:reset_digest] %>" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;color: #ffffff; background-color: #3AAEE0; border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; max-width: 150px; width: 110px; width: auto; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 20px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;mso-border-alt: none">
              <span style="font-size:12px;line-height:24px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 32px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 16px;">Corregir Datos</span></span>
            </a>
```

Thanks

Comment: is that what you see in the sent email?

Comment: Not exactly RubyMine iterprets it as text. I really have no form to validate it

Comment: You mean it looks the same in tests as well? Also have you tried HTML code for `&gt;` and `&lt;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to string concat your ruby vars into the if block and output the whole mso conditional, something like so in your case:

```
<%== '<!--[if mso]>
        <table width="100%" ...>
          <tr>
            <td style="...">
              <v:roundrect ... href="https://www.example.com/doctores/edit/' + @user[:id] + '/' + @user[:reset_digest] + '" style="..." ...>
                <w:anchorlock/>
                <center style="...">
      <![endif]-->' %>
```

Notice the use of the <%== 'raw' erb tag, I had inconsistent results with the regular escaped <%= tag.

Is frankly an ugly, hacky solution but then its not like using mso tags for emails is pretty ;)